How do digital watches steadily increment the internally stored time without fluctuations in speed while running other logic at the same time?
I'm not 100% sure if the right place to ask this is StackOverflow, Software Engineering, or here, but I'm going to guess here since this is related to hardware.
I was looking at my digital watch and the thought occurred to me that while digital watches have to constantly increment the time stored in it (probably stored as a Unix-style epoch,) they also have to do a lot of other logic every iteration of the logic loop, such as:

Checking whether the current time has reached/passed a set alarm every second.
Checking if a count-down timer has reach/passed zero, probably using something like (assuming epoch unit is in seconds) current_epoch > epoch_val_when_timer_was_first_started + total_num_secs_to_count_down_from + total_num_of_secs_paused_since_first_start?
Checking for user input (button presses) and responding accordingly.
Converting the epoch value to hours, minutes, and seconds and converting them to strings so they can be displayed on the screen.
Looking up which LEDs have to be lit up for each digit in the string (in a data structure stored in memory probably), and then "rendering" out the digits by lighting up the corresponding LEDs.

The number of things and what things specifically it has to do each "frame" would depend on user input, the number of active alarms (since it has to enumerate through all active alarms and check each one against the current epoch value,) whether the count-down timer is running, etc.
How does it manage to do all of the above without causing the time-keeping speed from fluctuating?
Since the code is directly running on the chip (I assume) and there's no OS, it can't look up the OS time. It also can't use multi-threading or multi-processing to split the epoch-incrementing loop from the remaining code logic for the same reason.
How does it manage it? Surely it can't be doing things all in a single thread, because that way the epoch-incrementing would slow down slightly every time it has more things to do (such as the user pressing a button, as that would cause it to have to run more logic to figure out the correct action to take.)
Is there a separate CPU hooked up to the same flash memory that runs at a rate of 1Hz and whose sole task is to run the folling code:
int main(){
    unsigned long long int epoch = 0;
    while(1){
        epoch++;
    }
    return 0;
}

That would probably cause race conditions with the other CPU if they access epoch at the same time in memory, but similiar idea. Does it run an embedded Linux system? If it does then the OS basically has to do the same thing of keeping time steadily while running other logic (user-mode processes in this case) at the same time. Maybe both questions actually boil down to the same question of how to run arbitrary logic while time-keeping at the same time without affecting the time-keeping speed.
Note: I'm a user-mode programmer with virtually zero experience with hardware and low-level stuff, so sorry if I'm making any big misunderstandings or mistakes in this question.

There is no code running on a basic wristwatch. It's all dedicated hardware.

What kind of watch are you looking at? Why would it have a CPU or keep time in Unix format? Digital watches generally have just a simple logic IC, implementing all the functions a clock or a watch with alarms and blinking in hardware so everything runs simultaneously. It's logic gates, no OS, no software, no CPU.

Um, my watch is a Casio AQS810W, and it has the features to configure up to 5 alarms, set a two-part countdown with optional number of repeats (so it would ring and then reset and start counting down again), start a stopwatch, configure a world clock with a specific time zone, swap the primary clock and the world clock, show solor battery level, etc. You mean all this functionality doesn't need any C code at all, and is implemented only in hardware? I thought it would be written in C and then compiled to asm and burned to the IC.

@ILikePython The thing is, it may be a chip that does everything in hardware, or it may be a programmable MCU. We can't know that unless you want to x-ray the chip. But it does not matter, it does what it does, whether or not someone wrote the software code to run on MCU or wrote the hardware description which was synthesized as the chip.

@Justme So say it's the former (does everything in hardware), does this mean the manufacturer would have to directly code in logic gates then? Or is there a special compiler or something that can "convert" C source code to a fixed circuit board that does the same thing?

...Is it even possible to code the end product directly using hardware logic gates?

@ILikePython You will use some HDL. Even Python or C can be used as HDL, see MyHDL or SystemC. You don't develop hardware with indivdual transistors or logic gates any more, just like you don't write code by writing individual bits or bytes one after another with pen and paper.

As was commented, your standard digital watch doesn’t have a processor running code. It’s going to have digital logic doing everything in hardware, all in a single custom chip. Economy-of-scale says so. In fact, the chip doesn’t even have a plastic case like more ICs. Instead the actual chip is bonded directly to the printed circuit board and the encased in a blob of epoxy.
Having said that, there is no reason that if someone wanted to build their own (bulky) digital watch, it couldn’t be done with a microcontroller (a CPU, RAM, FLASH memory, and peripherals all on one chip). You could even use an Arduino. It could be running simple code, in a single loop, as you imagine.
Now, to answer your question, the solution is hardware interrupts. The board would have sore of frequency reference, probably a quartz crystal, generating a signal at some fixed frequency. Every time the crystal generates a “tick”, it triggers a hardware interrupt. This stops the running code, saves the program’s state and starts running a different piece of code, called an “interrupt service routine” (ISR). In the simplest case, this ISR simply increments a global variable. Then the old program stare is restored by the hardware and the main code loop proceeds.
Whenever the main loop wants to know how many ticks of time have passed, it simply reads that global variable. Because the interrupts happen regardless of the loop state, it doesn’t matter what’s happening in the main loop.
This, by the way, is basically how every computer OS keeps time. At the lowest lever, there’s an ISR responding to a hardware “tick” and incrementing a global time variable.
This explanation is, of course, very simplified and high level.
Welcome to your first introduction to low-level software.

So instead of compiling hand-written C code to assembly and copying the assembly into the IC, the manufacturer writes the C code and "compiles" it (using some special compiler?) to a fixed circuit board that would do the same thing as the source code? Or do they not start with written source code at all, and instead "code" all the functionality directly using hardware logic gates? Wouldn't the latter be really, really hard? Or are both guesses wrong?

Also, about hardware interrupts. What if the "logic" loop is in the middle of reading the global variable in memory when the ISR freezes the main code and increments the global variable? Then the first half of the read would be the bits of the unincremented value, and the second half would be the bits of the incremented value. Wouldn't this cause bugs? Or is simply reading an integer value from memory an atomic operation that is impossible to be "in progress" when the ISR kicks in?

@ILikePython Since you seem to like Python, you can even use Python as HDL, see MyHDL. You describe what the chip must do in Python and in the end you get a result of hardware synthesis so that you can order a chip that does what you wrote in hardware logic gates. And regarding your worry about interrupts, you obviously write your program in a way that those kinds of bugs don't happen, but they will happen if you write it poorly.

@ILikePython For your first question, it’s not C code but something like VHDL (do a web search). For your second, that’s one of the simplifications I made. The are various solutions to synchronizing access to variable. For example, just before reading the time variable, the main loop executes an instruction causes the hardware to delay delivery of the interrupt. The code then reads the variable and then executes another instruction which releases the delay. This can introduce jitter in the time updating but as long as the delay is less than the time between two ticks, the time will update.

@DoxyLover For the second part: I see, that makes sense. So basically like threading.Lock() in Python. So the conclusion is that my digital watch's logic was either made by writing in C code and then compiling to asm and burned to a programmable chip inside it, or it was written in an HDL language and compiled to the design of a fixed chip (and manufactured)?
